# Is there something like a Single Pole Quad Throw Relay?

Tags: relay, multiplexer

I want to be able to route an analog signal through at least 4 different points. Now I know that I can't use analog multiplexers since the signal (high power) I want isn't within the range they can handle. So is there anything like an electromechanical multiplexer or something? Because a relay is fundamentally an electromechanical switch - usually single pole double throw. So, is there anything like a single pole quad throw version of it (if possible and as far as I have searched, none exist)

I know I can achieve this by using 3 relays in a tree like configuration but is there a more elegant solution or device?

The signal I intend on multiplexing is the commercial power line in India - 230VAC

Comment: What is the signal voltage/current exactly?

Comment: Alternatively, energising only one of 4 SPST relays may be simpler.

Comment: http://www.britishtelephones.com/howauto1.htm

Answer (score 3):

There is a family of relays known as stepper relays. They sequentially allow connection of an input to some number of outputs. They used to be used in the millions by the telephone company for connection of telephone calls on the basis of dial pulses created by a rotary dial telephone.

These days you may be best off selecting a suitable small relay that meets your signal carrying capabilities and then using multiples of them to create your selector.

You did not say anything about your signal characteristics. Maybe you could share that information as there may be folks here that know of suitable solid state switches that may work.

Comment: From what I have seen about stepper relays, the only difference seems to be in the way to they latch onto a contact. But essentially it still seems to remain a SPDT switching system. Or am I missing something? So, is there nothing like an electro-mechanical multiplexer or something?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but look for 4PDT "4 pole double throw" or 4PST "4 Pole Single Throw" relays. Thew will switch all four loads at the same time.  You have to know your voltage, current and it helps if you know the load type inductive/restive.  The current and voltage will have a big impact on cost.